# Is there any php library for using sql commands on xml files?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, database

I would like to store some information in xml format and query it whenever and I would also like to fetch data rows as arrays, like mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of [ODBC libraries available that use XML](http://www.datadirect.com/resources/odbc/xml-driver/index.html) as a backend.

I wouldn't do this though.  I'd stick with [PHP's built-in XML support](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Answer (score 0):

You might try [PHPLinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/). I havent used it but if the features are as complete as in .Net it should do exactly what you want, though you may have to deal with resultsets as `StdObject` or `ArrayObject` as opposed to arrays - not too sure about that. Still though it beats coding a SQL -> xpath solution yourself.